# How can I pass multiple arguments via xml for a custom setter when using Android data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

Suppose I have a custom setter method where I need two arguments:

```
@BindingAdapter({"imageUrl", "placeholder"})
public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl, Drawable drawable) {
     Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(imageUrl).placeholder(drawable).into(imageView);
}
```

What would the corresponding xml look like?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like it can be done like this:

`<ImageView app:imageUrl=“@{data.imageUrl}”
app:placeholder=“@{@drawable/placeholder}”/>`

see http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/data-binding/guide.html