# Android Two Way DataBinding Problem of Ternary Operator Must be Constant

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

**My `EditText` is like this:**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:text="@={viewModel.isAddCase? ``: `` + viewModel.currentStudent.age}"    //problem here
    android:inputType="number" />
```

I want the `EditText` not to show anything (empty String) based on the `isAddCase` variable, which is a `MutableLiveData<Boolean>` initilized when the `ViewModel` class object is created (inside the `init{}` block).

**This is the error I got:**

```
The expression '((viewModelIsAddCaseGetValue) ? ("") : (javaLangStringViewModelCurrentStudentAge))' cannot be inverted, so it cannot be used in a two-way binding

Details: The condition of a ternary operator must be constant: android.databinding.tool.writer.KCode@37a418c7
```

---

**UPDATE**

Even this doesn't work, shows the same error:

```
android:text="@={viewModel.currentStudent.age == 0? ``: `` + viewModel.currentStudent.age}"
```

I guess ternary operation just doesn't work well with two-way `DataBinding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out the perfect solution after these days:

**1. Create `BindingAdapter` Function:**

```
object DataBindingUtil {                                    //place in an util (singleton) class
    @BindingAdapter("android:text", "isAddCase")            //custom layout attribute, see below
    @JvmStatic                                              //required
    fun setText(editText: EditText, text: String, isAddCase: Boolean) {     //pass in argument
        if (isAddCase) editText.setText("") else editText.setText(text)
    }
}
```

- Passing multiple arguments from layout to `BindingAdapter` function:
  [How can I pass multiple arguments via xml for a custom setter when using Android data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921406/how-can-i-pass-multiple-arguments-via-xml-for-a-custom-setter-when-using-android)

**2. Apply Custom Attribute in `View`:**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="@={`` + viewModel.currentStudent.age}"        //two-way binding as usual
    app:isAddCase="@{viewModel.isAddCase}" />                   //here
```

---

- The `BindingAdapter` function is triggered only when using `EditText` and custom attribute **At The Same Time**.